# sql removing multiple records with mutltiple date values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sample data that I need to clean the records by specific date.  For this example, lets use anything older than march 2012 will need to be removed along with other related records.

Author Table

```
    Author       Book     date
-------------------------------------
    Smith        Bk1      01/01/2012
    Smith        Bk2      02/01/2012
    Smith        Bk3      02/25/2012
    Johnson      Bk1      06/01/2011
    Johnson      Bk2      09/01/2011
    Johnson      Bk3      03/01/2012
    Johnson      Bk4      01/01/2013
    Jones        BK1      01/01/2001
    Jones        BK2      01/01/2002
    Jones        BK3      01/01/2009
    Jones        BK4      08/01/2013
```

There is also a Book table

```
    Author       Book     info
-------------------------------------
    Smith        Bk1      asdfadf
    Smith        Bk2      asdfasdf
    Smith        Bk3      asdfadf
    Johnson      Bk1      asdfadf
    Johnson      Bk2      adsfasdf
    Johnson      Bk3      asdasdf
    Johnson      Bk4      asdfasdf
    Jones        BK1      asdfasdf
    Jones        BK2      adsfasdf
    Jones        BK3      adsfasdf
    Jones        BK4      adsfasdf
```

Above is the data set.  So if the Author has a book in the table that is older than 03/01/2013, then All of the records need to be removed. If they have at least one Book newer than the date specified then All records are kept.  In this scenario, the Jones records are the only ones to be kept in the table data set.  Once we figure which Author has been filtered then we would remove the records from the Book table, and then the Author table.

Thanks for any help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far, I will try them out.  I also forgot to add the second table, not sure if this complicates things or not.  Thanks again guys!

Comment: I just tested Max's and Guttsy's answers and they both work well.  Thanks for all the help.  You guys made it look too easy, I think I might have been over thinking it.

Comment: Just to let everyone know...both of these answers work.  Thanks again guys.

Comment: I have a similar question regarding this post.  Should I ask here or post a new question?
Say I want to clean up both tables, and I need to refer the date field in the Author Table.   In this example, I would want to query the Author table distinct by Author but return the most recent date from the rows for each author.
Once I get the most recent date from the query, I would use that to remove all authors whose most recent date is older than a specified date, ie 3/1/2012.
Once I get this value by author, I would delete from book table and then author.

Comment: Please disregard.  comment above

Answer (score 2):

This appears to do what you want (I've added code to provide a proof-of-concept using the TempDB):

```
USE tempdb;

/* Create the same tables, and insert test data */
CREATE TABLE Authors
(
    Author nvarchar(255)
    , Book nvarchar(255)
    , BookDate datetime
);

INSERT INTO Authors VALUES ('joe','book1',GetDate()-100); --100 days old
INSERT INTO Authors VALUES ('joe','book2',GetDate()-200); --200 days old
INSERT INTO Authors VALUES ('joe','book3',GetDate()-300); --300 days old
INSERT INTO Authors VALUES ('sam','book4',GetDate()-400); --etc
INSERT INTO Authors VALUES ('sam','book5',GetDate()-500);
INSERT INTO Authors VALUES ('sam','book6',GetDate()-600);

CREATE TABLE Books
(
    Author nvarchar(255)
    , Book nvarchar(255)
    , Info nvarchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Books VALUES ('joe','book1','asdf');
INSERT INTO Books VALUES ('joe','book2','asdfg');
INSERT INTO Books VALUES ('joe','book3','asdfh');
INSERT INTO Books VALUES ('sam','book4','asdf');
INSERT INTO Books VALUES ('sam','book5','bsdf');
INSERT INTO Books VALUES ('sam','book6','csdf');

/* This statement deletes rows from the dependent table, Books */
DELETE  
FROM Books 
FROM Books LEFT JOIN 
(       /* This selects all Authors with books in the past 300 days */
    SELECT Author 
    FROM Authors
    WHERE BookDate >= GetDate()-300 
) t2 ON Books.Author = t2.Author
WHERE t2.Author IS NULL; /* This ensures rows from Books only get deleted
                                when for Authors that DON'T have books in the
                                past 300 days */

/* This statement deletes rows from the main table, Authors */
DELETE  
FROM Authors 
FROM Authors LEFT JOIN 
(       /* This selects all Authors with books in the past 300 days */
    SELECT Author 
    FROM Authors
    WHERE BookDate >= GetDate()-300 
) t2 ON Authors.Author = t2.Author
WHERE t2.Author IS NULL; /* This ensures rows from Books only get deleted
                                when for Authors that DON'T have books in the
                                past 300 days */

SELECT * FROM Books;
SELECT * FROM Authors;
```

Only Sam's rows will be deleted since he is the only author with no book newer than 300 days old.

Comment: If I wanted to delete from tbl2 before tbl, would I just replace tbl with tbl2.  something like "Delete from tbl2 from tbl2 left join" and everything else would be the same, correct?  reason being, that I would like to remove from 2nd table first, then clean up the 1st table.

Comment: You need to clean up any tables that are dependent on the primary table.  In this instance your `Books` table doesn't have a date field, therefore it is dependent on the `Authors` table.  If you delete authors first, you will not have any way of deleting rows from Books.  In short, you need to delete from Books, then delete from Authors.

Comment: Yes, perfect, I that looks like what I wanted it to do.

Comment: Understood on the deleting dependent tables first, I am trying to grasp the part where you are selecting from Authors and filtering by bookdate.  How does sql know to use the most recent date rather than a random date from the different books?  I can just accept the fact that sql "just knows", but it would be nice to see how sql comes to this conclusion.  Thanks again!

Comment: SQL doesn't "come to this conclusion", it merely looks to see if the "SELECT Author 
    FROM Authors
    WHERE BookDate >= GetDate()-300" contains any records; if not, it deletes the associated Author rows.

Answer (score 1):

Delete from table 1 first:

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE Author NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Author 
   FROM Table1 WHERE Date >= '2013-03-01')
```

Then from table 2:

```
DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE Author NOT IN (SELECT Author FROM Table1)
```

Not the most beautiful SQL I have ever written, but it should suffice. Something like this wouldn't work if you had normalized tables with foreign keys, but I don't think that is the case right now.

If you insist on running it in the opposite order:

```
DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE Author NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Author 
    FROM Table1 WHERE Date >= '2013-03-01')

DELETE FROM Table1
    WHERE Author NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Author FROM Table2)
```

Comment: So Run the With Statement first to remove from the Table2, then Run another with statement to remove from table1.  I think that will be easy enough.  I will give that a try.

Comment: Okay, from looking at the statement, It would only have 1 record left from table 1.  Since Jones has 1 book newer than the date specified then all of Jones books needs to be left in the tables.

Comment: @eripey The syntax was a bit off, so I cleaned it up again. This did not have any effect on how the SQL was intended to work, however. I believe your assessment about the remaining rows was incorrect.

Comment: In the Select distinct, sql knows to look for the most recent date? If this works, it's a lot shorter.  I will try.

Comment: I tried out your second block of code and it works, a lot shorter code too.  Still don't understand how it works, how sql knows to differentiate from all the different dates from Table1.

Comment: Can you Edit on the second block of code to Delete from Table1 with using the Date and not use Table2?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, I used the First select distinct.

Comment: So, everything is working ok? Any other questions? Basically, we are deleting records from either table based on author name, and to get the list of authors to delete from the table, we query table 1 and find authors who only have books with the date after the one you specified. Once records are deleted from one table, depending on which table you delete first, you can do the same exact thing to the other table. I believe that's what you meant when you said "I used the first select distinct."

Comment: Would it make sense by somehow getting a max date?  Go through the list of distinct authors and find the most recent date and compare the date to be purged?  For instance smith date is 02/25/2012, Johnson date is 01/01/2013 and Jones date is 08/01/2013.

Comment: There seem to be many different acceptable ways to solve this problem. Yes, you could get the max date for each author (`SELECT MAX(Date), Author FROM Table1 GROUP BY Author`) and then join/use that in another query to do the deletion, but it doesn't really add any value. It just adds more complexity because you're dealing with dates more than once.

Comment: After reading more carefully on this, It looks like it doesn't look through all the date fields to determine one most recent date, rather these queries and find any instance that matches the criteria.